# mod rewrite for zend framework with 2 public folders

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework, mod-rewrite

Hello I have the following files structure:

```
/public_html(docroot)
    - /public
        /css
        /js
        index.php
    - /application
    - /library
```

Note: I cannot change this structure. What I want: all requests to files should open files from public folder, all other requests should go to the index.php. Currently I have the next .htaccess in public_html:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

But it works just with `http://hostname/public`. How can it work without `public`? Thanks.

Comment: You could change the last RewriteRule to `RewriteRule ^.*$ /public/index.php [NC,L]`. I'm not sure about the preceding /, so if it's not working try omitting it.

Comment: It doesn't work. See my answer below.

Comment: Why can't you set your DocumentRoot to `public_html`? This way all files in `public_html` are public and served as-is and your `application`, `library` and other folders are hidden, giving you more security.

Comment: I know, that it's better, but see correctly my question. I cannot change file structure (hosting). For security i am using .htaccess with "deny from all" for `application` and `library`. Thanks for all, i have found the way (in my answer below).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found an answer:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !public/
RewriteRule (.*) /public/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```